Running a python script with a Azure SQL connection on Heroku
I have this simple python script, which works fine on local with either ODBC Driver 17 or ODBC Driver 18, the database is a Azure SQL db.
import pyodbc

server = 'tcp:db.database.windows.net'  
user = 'myUser'           
password = 'myPw.'                  
database = 'myDB'                       
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

try:

    conn_str = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={user};PWD={password}'
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.clientes")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    conn.close()
except pyodbc.Error as e:
    print(f"Error en la conexión: {e}")

when I deploy the script to Heroku, and run it, I get this Error en la conexión: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [OpenSSL library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 is installed] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')
I added these buildpacks but I got the same error
enter image description here
Any ideas?
I ran it, I should expect to get results back from the database, but looks like I'm getting errors trying to connect the DB.

('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [OpenSSL library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 is installed] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The error you're encountering ([Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [OpenSSL library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 is installed]) on Heroku occurs because the ODBC Driver for SQL Server requires OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 to handle SSL/TLS encryption, and it seems that OpenSSL is either not installed or not accessible on the Heroku environment.
You can follow below procedure to run a Python script on Heroku that connects to an Azure SQL database:

Create a Python script: Write your Python script that connects to the Azure SQL database using the appropriate libraries, like pyodbc or pymssql.

Set up your Azure SQL database: Make sure your Azure SQL database is properly configured and accessible from outside sources if necessary.

Deploy your Python script to Heroku:
– Create a requirements.txt file with the necessary dependencies, including libraries like pyodbc or pymssql.
– You can use a Procfile to define how Heroku should run your Python script.
– Create a Heroku app and deploy your code to it using Git.

Set environment variables:
– Ensure that all relevant connection information, such as the Azure SQL server name, database name, username, password, and any other required settings, are stored as environmental variables in Heroku.
– You can set these variables either using the Heroku CLI or through the Heroku dashboard.

Modify your Python script to read these environmental variables for the connection settings to the Azure SQL database as below:
import pyodbc
import os

server = os.getenv("AZURE_SQL_SERVER")
database = os.getenv("AZURE_SQL_DATABASE")
username = os.getenv("AZURE_SQL_USERNAME")
password = os.getenv("AZURE_SQL_PASSWORD")
conn_str = f"DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}"
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)



For more information you can refer to this.
